# Is there a way set a login screen for Spring Security with fxml?

Tags: spring, javafx, spring-security, fxml

Right now I have a really simple Spring Boot desktop application. I incoperated the basics of Spring Security in that application (see code down below), but if I look up on how to make a custom login screen inside of my application, people only talk about using Spring Security with web applications. Is there a way to do this inside my application (preferably with FXML)?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/endpoint1").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/endpoint2").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin()
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sure that using Spring security that way for a java fx application is a good idea :thinking: I would think not at all if you ask me it is not built for that. Building java fx applications with spring boot is good but the secuity stuff, that's made to secure endpoints etc. login, user sessions all of which is a little different I'd say. ...."WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter "

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Do you happen to know an alternative to spring security that still works well with spring (because Spring is a requirement for my assignment)?

Comment: Well just use the rest of spring right...Dependency injection and all the other stuff that comes with it

Comment: Here is a javafx application using spring boot https://github.com/FAForever/faf-moderator-client

Comment: Most of Spring Security is concerned with routing the requests in a web application; e.g. user sends a request for a restricted resource - spring checks if the user is already authenticated and returns the requested resource if so, otherwise the user is redirected to a login. Spring then processes the login, compares against some authentication scheme, and then if the login is successful sends the originally-requested resource. The vast majority of that work is in the routing, and it's necessary because http allows any user to request any resource at any time.

Comment: That's not the case in your JavaFX application; you'll presumably show the login screen at startup, and then not allow the user to proceed unless they successfully authenticate. There's no complex re-routing of requests to be managed. The only part of Spring Security that might be useful is the actual authentication; so how do you want that to happen? Are you authenticating against a database? Against some kind of existing directory server?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076784/spring-security-in-standalone-application) shows a basic approach to authenticating a desktop app against an LDAP server. If you really have an application where parts of the app need authentication, and/or specific authorization, you could probably create a fairly simple class that manages loading FXML files and intercepts anything that requires authorization - however I'm guessing from the question you don't need that.